# correcting the select options in html using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Contact Us</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container" ng-controller="ContactController">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">Contact Us</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h3>Contact Us</h3>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h3>Location Information</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
                <h5>Our Address</h5>
                <address style="font-size: 100%">
                    121, Clear Water Bay Road
                    <br> Clear Water Bay, Kowloon
                    <br> HONG KONG
                    <br>
                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>: +852 1234 5678
                    <br>
                    <i class="fa fa-fax"></i>: +852 8765 4321
                    <br>
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>:
                    <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
                </address>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
                <h5>Map of our Location</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-11 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="tel:+85212345678">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Call</a>
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="fa fa-skype"></i> Skype</a>
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="mailto:confusion@food.net">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Email</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h3>Send us your Feedback</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9" ng-controller="FeedbackController">
                <form class="form-horizontal" name="feedbackForm" ng-submit="sendFeedback()" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : feedbackForm.firstname.$error.required && !feedbackForm.firstname.$pristine }">
                        <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" ng-model="feedback.firstName"
                                required>
                            <span ng-show="feedbackForm.firstname.$error.required && !feedbackForm.firstname.$pristine" class="help-block">Your First name is required.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : feedbackForm.lastname.$error.required && !feedbackForm.lastname.$pristine }">
                        <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" ng-model="feedback.lastName"
                                required>
                            <span ng-show="feedbackForm.lastname.$error.required && !feedbackForm.lastname.$pristine" class="help-block">Your Last name is required.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="telnum" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contact Tel.</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon">(</div>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Area code" ng-model="feedback.tel.areaCode">
                                <div class="input-group-addon">)</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-7">
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telnum" name="telnum" placeholder="Tel. number" ng-model="feedback.tel.number">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error has-feedback' : feedbackForm.emailid.$invalid && !feedbackForm.emailid.$pristine }">
                        <label for="emailid" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailid" name="emailid" placeholder="Email" ng-model="feedback.email" required>
                            <span ng-show="feedbackForm.emailid.$invalid && !feedbackForm.emailid.$pristine" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"
                                aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span ng-show="(feedbackForm.emailid.$invalid ||
                                            feedbackForm.emailid.$error.required) &&
                                            !feedbackForm.emailid.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email address.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : invalidChannelSelection }">
                        <div class="checkbox col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="feedback.agree">
                                <strong>May we contact you?</strong>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1" ng-show="feedback.agree">
                            <select class="form-control" ng-model="feedback.mychannel" ng-options="channel.value as channel.label for channel in channels">
                                <option value="">Tel. or Email?</option>
                            </select>
                            <span ng-show="invalidChannelSelection" class="help-block">Select an option.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="feedback" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Feedback</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="12" ng-model="feedback.comments">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="feedbackForm.$invalid">Send Feedback</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                <h3>Your Current Feedback:</h3>
                <p>{{feedback.firstName}} {{feedback.lastName | uppercase }}</p>
                <p>Contact Tel.: ({{feedback.tel.areaCode}}) {{feedback.tel.number}}</p>
                <p>Contact Email: {{feedback.email}}</p>
                <p ng-show="feedback.agree">Contact by: {{feedback.mychannel}}</p>
                <p>Comments: {{feedback.comments}}</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

</body>

</html>
```

app.js file

```
'use strict';
angular.module('confusionApp', [])
    .controller('MenuController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.tab = 1;
        $scope.filtText = '';
        $scope.showDetails = false;

        $scope.dishes = [{
                name: 'Uthapizza',
                image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                category: 'mains',
                label: 'Hot',
                price: '4.99',
                description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                comment: ''
            },

            {
                name: 'Zucchipakoda',
                image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
                category: 'appetizer',
                label: '',
                price: '1.99',
                description: 'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
                comment: ''
            },

            {
                name: 'Vadonut',
                image: 'images/vadonut.png',
                category: 'appetizer',
                label: 'New',
                price: '1.99',
                description: 'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
                comment: ''
            },

            {
                name: 'ElaiCheese Cake',
                image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
                category: 'dessert',
                label: '',
                price: '2.99',
                description: 'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
                comment: ''
            }
        ];

        $scope.select = function (setTab) {
            $scope.tab = setTab;

            if (setTab === 2) {
                $scope.filtText = "appetizer";
            } else if (setTab === 3) {
                $scope.filtText = "mains";
            } else if (setTab === 4) {
                $scope.filtText = "dessert";
            } else {
                $scope.filtText = "";
            }
        };

        $scope.isSelected = function (checkTab) {
            return ($scope.tab === checkTab);
        };
        $scope.toggleDetails = function () {
            $scope.showDetails = !$scope.showDetails;
        };
    }])
    .controller('ContactController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.feedback = {
            mychannel: "",
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            agree: false,
            email: ""
        };
        var channels = [{
            value: "tel",
            label: "Tel."
        }, {
            value: "Email",
            label: "Email"
        }];
        $scope.channels = channels;
        $scope.invalidChannelSelection = false;
    }])

    .controller('FeedbackController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.sendFeedback = function () {
            console.log($scope.feedback);
            if ($scope.feedback.agree && ($scope.feedback.mychannel === "") && !$scope.feedback.mychannel) {
                $scope.invalidChannelSelection = true;
                console.log('incorrect');
            } else {
                $scope.invalidChannelSelection = false;
                $scope.feedback = {
                    mychannel: "",
                    firstName: "",
                    lastName: "",
                    agree: false,
                    email: ""
                };
                $scope.feedback.mychannel = "";

                $scope.feedbackForm.$setPristine();
                console.log($scope.feedback);
            }
        };

    }]);
```

Please help with the code correction. I see an extra empty option in the HTML web application when I check the checkbox "may we contact you?". Instead, I need to get only 3 options without the first option which is empty. Please solve the issue. Thank you in advance.

[This is the output which I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqrxf.png)
[This should be the actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrdIr.png)

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change**

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="feedback.mychannel" ng-options="channel.value as channel.label for channel in channels">
                                <option value="">Tel. or Email?</option>
                            </select>
```

**To**

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="feedback.mychannel" ng-options="channel.value as channel.label for channel in channels" ng-init="feedback.mychannel =channels[0].value">
                            </select>
```

and set channels like

```
 $scope.channels = [{
            value: "",
            label: "Tel. or Email"
        },{
            value: "tel",
            label: "Tel."
        }, {
            value: "Email",
            label: "Email"
        }];
```

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujfdz6gL/)